# How do I customize the location of a field?

Tags: theming

I have following block made with the Views module.

> [image]

I need somehow, with the help of template I think, to place text and image in one line so it will be in one row.

How can I do that?

I tried creating a custom view template, but I do not have possibility to place those fields in that template as there isn't any variable. `kint()` shows me only content variables.